# Eclipse Terminal Not Updating / Weird Behaviour

Tags: eclipse, maven, terminal, console

I am using Eclipse (Theme = DevStyle) for Development of Java Maven Projects.
When working within Eclipse with a Windows Terminal there's very weird behaviour, where the terminal view inside eclipse doesn't update according to the commands like shown in the GIF below:

[image: Console Behaviour]

Anyone knows a fix for this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer howlger. Uninstalling DevStyle and creating a new workspace  does not fix my Problem. :(

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the current Eclipse 2022-03 on Window 10. Have you uninstalled all plugins from this vendor?

Comment: Which commands are we looking at? Just `cls`?

Comment: Adding to Brian's comment, there was a bug in the Eclipse terminal component that was directly caused by Windows library versions. If you're on Windows, you might want to give it a look there for the cause and how to fix it: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547028

Comment: yes as it would seem it is only `cls` . Also i am on windows. and thank you @ToddWilliams. Following this bug and implementing the fix was the solution!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [this Link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547028) provided by @Todd Williams (original commit was by @Jonah Graham) the problem lies with Windows Pseudo Console:

> On Windows the terminal uses the amazing WinPTY library to provide a PTY as Windows did not come with one. For the last number of years, Windows 10 has a native version called Windows Pseudo Console (ConPTY) which programs such as VSCode and Eclipse Theia have converted to using, in part because of the fundamental bugs that can't be fixed in WinPTY. The WinPTY version in Eclipse is also quite out of date, and hard to develop as it is interfaced to by JNI.

Therefore disabling Windows Pseudo Console (ConPTY) by starting Eclipse with the argument `-vmargs -Dorg.eclipse.cdt.core.conpty_enabled=false` fixes the problem.

Or you can add the argument to the `eclipse.ini` file (found in the Eclipse Root Folder)

```
...
-vmargs
-Dorg.eclipse.cdt.core.conpty_enabled=false
...
```

Comment: The mentioned bug was closed as a duplicate of another already fixed bug. Which version of _TM Terminal_ do you have exactly (see _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_)? Does this issue still exist in the current Eclipse with the current _TM Terminal_ plugin on a current Windows?

Comment: My Eclipse Version is 2022.3 and the TM Terminal is 10.6.0.202201121907; windows version is 10.0 Build 18363

Comment: In your screenshot it says `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.2094]` which is [Windows 10 version 1909](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_1909), but in a [current Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history#Version_21H2_%28November_2021_Update%29) you would get something like `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1586]`. Please be fair and name the author of your quote, not the person who googled it. Are you referring to [this commit by Jonah Graham](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/commit/?id=4e9223995214cdb2296280e592e1e6ed604bf583)?